# Can't multiply matrix with armadillo

Tags: c++, codeblocks, armadillo

I can not do matrix multiplications with armadillo. I don't know if there are more features I can't use. So far, I've only been using vectors and dot product with no problem.
Basically:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <armadillo>

using namespace std;
using namespace arma;

int main(){
    //this works
    vec v = randu<vec>(10);
    cout<<dot(v,v)<<endl;

    int n =5;
    //this doesn't work
    mat M = randu<mat>(n,n); // program compiles but stops running when reaches here
    cout<<M*M<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I am using the newest version of codeblock and armadillo. OS is windows 7. I've included the lapack and blas libraries in the compiler linker settings and blas_win64_MT and lapack_win64_MT are both in PATH. And I've also included de armadillo folder in the search directory. In config.hpp (armadillo folder), #define ARMA_USE_LAPACK and #define ARMA_USE_BLAS are uncommented. #define ARMA_USE_WRAPPER is commented. Also, I have tried to add -lapack -lblas to the build->project options->compiler->other options and to build->project options->linker setting->other options, but I had no success. Same thing happened when I tried to add -larmadillo to the compiler with #define ARMA_USE_WRAPPER uncommented.
What am I missing?

Comment: It's really hard to know what you mean by "it doesn't work".  I can only assume that you mean "it doesn't compile", and that the error messages (which you neglected to show) point to the fact that `n` is not defined.

Comment: I forgot to write it, but n was definided. The program compiles. But when it runs, it stops working after printing de dot product.

Answer (score 2):

Your program is *of course* perfectly fine as Armadillo is a well-designed and delivered library.

What may not be right is your installation, or local setup. Only you can figure that out.

On my box, and on the command-line -- where I only need to link with `libarmadillo` which itself has linkage to lapack and blas:

```
edd@max:/tmp$ g++ -o arma5by5 arma5by5.cpp -larmadillo
edd@max:/tmp$ ./arma5by5 
4.06892
   1.5043   1.3996   0.6353   0.8246   1.4694
   1.6543   1.6822   0.4338   0.6739   1.5782
   1.3145   1.2759   0.3825   0.4967   1.2959
   1.4222   1.4584   1.0028   1.3742   1.3593
   1.6126   1.7886   0.4599   0.8348   1.5648

edd@max:/tmp$
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When I add -larmadillo to the compiler line, I get the following: cannot find larmadillo. I know it is a different question, but how do I install it so that the compiler can find it?

Comment: This is all elementary, and you're having a hard time as you are on the least developer-friendly OS.  You need to set the `-Lpath/to/dir/with/lib` option.  Consult your IDE documentation or do it on the command-line.

Comment: Since you're on Windows, maybe you could try [ceemple](http://www.ceemple.com). It comes with Armadillo installed... at least I think so. It's not available for Mac.

Comment: I tried the same thing on a Linux system and got the same error. At least, I was told the problem was a "segmentation fault". So now, I believe there is a bug in either armadillo or in the blas library that comes with it. Do you think I should email armadillo team?

Comment: If you use the **same wrong and incomplete linker instruction** of course you get the same result.  As I told you before, it is your error for not linking correctly.

Comment: You mean that I am linking it the wrong way? If that is right, how is it possible that I can use some functions/operators but not all of them?

Comment: I'm having a similar problem. Trying to get to work armadillo in a cluster environment without root permissions, I've tried this:
g++ -std=c++0x example.cpp -o example -O2 -I /some_path/armadillo-9.100.5/include
-L /some_path/armadillo-9.100.5/libarmadillo.so.9.100.5  -larmadillo -lblas -llapack

However, this doesn't work and it returns me the following error:
/local1/opt/rh/devtoolset-6/root/usr/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/6.3.1/ld: cannot find -\
larmadillo

any ideas what could be wrong here? Why does it not work if I'm telling where the library lives? Many thanks!